# XeLaTeX does not find fontspec any longer after TeXLive update

Tags: xetex, errors, installing, fontspec

I am using XeLaTeX in TeX Live suites 2010 and everything was going well before I did an upgrade via TeX Live Manager minutes ago. Now every document I compile gets a "File not found" error as the title suggests. But actually `fontspec.sty` is lying well under `texlive\2010\tex\latex\fontspec` so I don't understand why it complains about that.

Does anyone have the same situation?

Comment: @user4457: A suggestion: Change your username to something more telling than "user4457".

Comment: @user4457. Perhaps something went wrong with the update. Could you try `sudo texhash` at the Terminal and see if that helps (it rebuilds the file database).

Comment: @lockstep, nice to meet you, I am ziyuang. @Joseph-Wright, But I am using Windows. @Martin-Scharrer, thanks for refining my question.

Comment: Nice to meet you, too. I started as "user510". ;-)

Answer (score 3):

OK, I fixed it. Just copy the folder `texlive\2010\tex\latex\fontspec` to `texlive\2010\texmf-dist\tex\latex\fontspec`. There will be some other similar errors though. If it said "**! Package graphics Error: No driver specified.**", copy `texlive\2010\tex\latex\latexconfig\graphics.cfg` to the folder `texlive\2010\texmf-dist\tex\latex\graphics`. If it still doesn't work, do some database refresh job in `tlmgr`.

Comment: ziyuang, @Martin's suggestion is a good one; however, you'll have to wait about 14 more hours before you can accept your answer (as far as I know).